# Which Plugin I am really using in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, plugins

I have Android Studio Hedgehog 2023.1.1

I installed it with the bundle option. So I have a lot of enabled Plugins.

But how do I identify which ones I am really using?

For instance I do not use version control yet so I disabled those related plugins. But there are many more that don't know if I am using them. For example I suspect that I do not use the plugin for C/C++ Language since I am programing in Kotlin but I really do not know if that is used for something else. Many others I really don't have a clue.

Is there a report or something that I can activate to identify the plugins that I really use?